# Why don't classes in the JCL explicitly use `@Override` on their `toString()` methods?

Tags: java

The API specification [page for the Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) for the method `toString()` states:

> "It is recommended that all subclasses override this method."

Therefore I expect to see the `@Override` annotation in a lot of classes in the Java Class Library. I looked, and it is neither present in the class '[Class](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Class.java.html)' nor the class 'String'.

These are the only two I checked, but assuming this is the case for all classes in the JCL, why don't they use the `@Override` annotation?

Is it for performance reasons?
Is it because the classes were written before `@Override` was introduced?

I was under the impression that using `@Override` liberally was [good programming practice](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=223).

Comment: Maybe because a lot of this code would have been written before `@Override` existed?

Comment: The `@Override` annotation (not statement) is there for the person looking at the code to let them know the method has been overridden. Some IDE's will remind you to put it in. I can't speak to it having better performance, but I doubt it does. I'd be happy to stand corrected on that.

Comment: I doubt it's performance-related.  `@Override` is a compile-time annotation that is not known at runtime.

Comment: Oh, wait, JDK 1.5 is Java 5 right? So, yeah, it could be because the code was written before `@Override` was introduced. I was going to put that as a suggestion in my question, but I thought 1.5 was like Java 1.5! I wasn’t concentrating!

Comment: @DrewKennedy thx, I will make correction (`@Override` is an annotation).

Comment: @DrewKennedy Oh, and its more than just for letting ppl know. Its to mitigate against typographical errors - like if a programmer is overriding a method, but spells the method wrong, this becomes an entirely different method, and you have failed to correctly override the parent's method.

Comment: Exactly. I could be wrong, but that's pretty much what it's there for - just an aid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be understood if you understand why `@Override` is used. The thing is that it provides benefits for sub-class maintainers only.

The main usage is like following: library A has a class `SecurityManager`, which has method `allowed`. Bob uses A at his project, he extended `SecurityManager`, and overridden `allowed` in his code. However `allowed` is used only by `SecurityManager`'s internal logic, so Bob never calls it in his code, but he relies that library will use his implementation instead of basic. Then maintainers of the library created a new major version, with some breaking changes - and renamed the method to `isAllowed`. Bob downloaded the new version and compiler said to him "`@Override` doesn't override anything - recheck your code", and Bob saw that method's name changed, and fixed that.

However java is backwards compatible, so there is no sense in expecting that `toString` will be removed or renamed at some point of time. That's why there is no sense in adding `@Override` for `Object`'s methods.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you provide any supporting links?

Comment: @JohnADurston, I'm telling from my experience, so I'm unsure what links you are interested in. Never saw any other practical benefit from it, especially considering that software developers override methods by code-generation tools from IDEs. TBH explanations like "you will see that your `equals` has incorrect signature with `@Override`" are great, but they never occur IRL because you always test your code at least once, at least by manual execution.